# How to call base class indexer property in c++/cli?

Tags: c++-cli

I'm trying to implement a class inheriting from the generic `List<T>` class:

```
Class MyList::List<MyClass>
```

I want to call the `List<T>::Item[Int32]` indexer property in one of my methods, but I couldn't figure out how to do it.

I tried `List<MyClass>::[i]` and `List<MyClass>::Item[i]`, but neither works.

I know, to call other methods from `List<MyClass>`, for example `Add`, I can just do `List<MyClass>::Add(myInstance)`.

(In my real code, I intend to implement a class that stores a list of images. Depending on some conditions, my indexer would either return the raw image or a processed image.  As such I need to include some logic in the getter for the indexer.)

Comment: Are you re-implementing the indexer in your derived class?

Comment: Yes. I intend to implement a class that stores a list of images. Depending on some conditions, my indexer would either return the raw image or a processed image.

Comment: Then don't inherit from `List<T>`, it's not designed for its indexer to be overridden.  The .Net framework does support [interface re-implementation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/interfaces#interface-re-implementation) by derived classes but you cannot make the base class call the replacement method internally.

Comment: Instead, consider inheriting from `System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection<T>`, it **is** designed for that purpose as it allows you to override [`SetItem()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.objectmodel.collection-1.setitem?view=netframework-4.8) and `InsertItem(int index, T item)`.  Or make your own class that implements `IList<T>` and contains an internal `List<T>` (decorator or adapter pattern).

Comment: What do you mean `List<T>` is not designed for its indexer to be overridden? Is that because it's highly optimized and overriding it would hurt performance?

Comment: OK, but I don't think I need to make the base class call the replacement method internally for my class.

Comment: Answer updated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since [`List<T>.Item[Int32]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.item#System_Collections_Generic_List_1_Item_System_Int32_) is a default indexer, you can just do `this[i]`.  For instance:

```
public ref class MyList : System::Collections::Generic::List<MyClass ^>
{
public:
    int CountNonNull();
};

int MyList::CountNonNull()
{
    int nonNull = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < Count; i++)
    {
        if (this[i] != nullptr)
            nonNull++;
    }
    return nonNull;
}
```

Or if you prefer you can use the "default indexer" property name `default[i]` explicitly:

```
if (this->default[i] != nullptr)
    nonNull++;
```

`List<MyClass ^>::default[i]` is also valid and can be used to call the base indexer when overriding the indexer itself.

See: *[How to: Use Properties in C++/CLI: Indexed properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/dotnet/how-to-use-properties-in-cpp-cli?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=vs-2019#indexed-properties)*.

---

In comments you write that you do intend to override the `List<T>.Item[Int32]` default indexer:

> I intend to implement a class that stores a list of images. Depending on some conditions, my indexer would either return the raw image or a processed image.

If so, I don't recommend inheriting from `List<T>` because [`List<T>.Item[Int32]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.item#System_Collections_Generic_List_1_Item_System_Int32_) is **not virtual** and not intended to be overridden.  Thus you will only be able to hide it via [interface re-implementation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/interfaces#interface-re-implementation).  But this leaves your app open to a possible bug: if your `MyList` is ever upcast to the base class `List<MyClass ^>`, then the replacement indexer will not be called.  Even worse, it seems that the enumerator returned by [`List<T>.GetEnumerator()`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/generic/list.cs,1140) will not call your replacement indexer, so simply iterating through a `MyList` will result in unprocessed items being returned.

To see what I mean, consider the following synthetic example:

```
ref class MyList;

public ref class MyClass
{
public:
    property bool Processed;
};

public ref class MyList : List<MyClass ^>, IList<MyClass ^>
{
public:
   // default indexer
    virtual property MyClass^ default[int] 
    {
        MyClass^ get(int index) new = IList<MyClass ^>::default::get  // hiding + interface reimplementation of default::get method
        { 
            MyClass^ item = List<MyClass ^>::default[index]; // Call base default indexer
            item = ProcessItem(item);                        // Add your custom logic here
            return item;                                     // return the item
        }
        void set(int index, MyClass^ value) new = IList<MyClass ^>::default::set // hiding + interface reimplementation of default::set method
        {
            List<MyClass ^>::default[index] = value;         // Call base default indexer
        }
    }

private:
    MyClass^ ProcessItem(MyClass ^item)
    {
        // Add your custom logic here
        if (item != nullptr)
            item->Processed = true;
        return item;
    }
};
```

Here the `get` method calls `ProcessItem()` for processing before being returned.  (Your image processing would go here; in the example a `bool` is set to `true`.)

Now consider the following unit test:

```
MyList ^list = gcnew MyList();

list->Add(gcnew MyClass());
for each (MyClass^ item in list)
    Debug::Assert(item->Processed); // FAILS because enumerator doesn't call indexer!

list->Add(gcnew MyClass());
Debug::Assert(list[list->Count-1]->Processed); // Passes because re-implemented Add() was called.

// Upcast to base class
List<MyClass ^>^ baseList = list;
baseList->Add(gcnew MyClass());
Debug::Assert(baseList[list->Count-1]->Processed); // FAILS because re-implemented Add() was NOT called!

// Upcast to interface
IList<MyClass ^>^ iList = list;
iList->Add(gcnew MyClass());
Debug::Assert(iList[iList->Count-1]->Processed); // Passes because re-implemented Add() was called.
```

While the second and fourth asserts pass, the first and third fail because the replacement `get()` method is not getting called.  And this really can't be avoided; interface re-implementation via the `new` keyword doesn't actually override the base implementation, it creates a new implementation with a new slot in the vtable.  See: *[new (new slot in vtable) (C++/CLI and C++/CX)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/extensions/new-new-slot-in-vtable-cpp-component-extensions?view=vs-2019)*.

So, what are your options?

Firstly, if the necessary image processing can be done when **adding** the image to the collection, you can inherit from [`System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.objectmodel.collection-1?view=netframework-4.8) which provides protected virtual methods that are called whenever items are added or removed from the collection.  (This is the base class for `ObservableCollection<T>`.)

Thus if we define `MyList` as follows:

```
public ref class MyList : Collection<MyClass ^>
{
protected:
    virtual void InsertItem(int index, MyClass ^ item) override
    {
        Collection<MyClass ^>::InsertItem(index, ProcessItem(item));
    }

    virtual void SetItem(int index, MyClass ^ item) override
    {
        Collection<MyClass ^>::InsertItem(index, ProcessItem(item));
    }

private:
    MyClass^ ProcessItem(MyClass ^item)
    {
        // Add your custom logic here
        if (item != nullptr)
            item->Processed = true;
        return item;
    }
};
```

Then all four asserts now pass:

```
MyList ^list = gcnew MyList();

list->Add(gcnew MyClass());
for each (MyClass^ item in list)
    Debug::Assert(item->Processed); // Passes

list->Add(gcnew MyClass());
Debug::Assert(list[list->Count-1]->Processed); // Passes

// Upcast to base class
Collection<MyClass ^>^ baseList = list;
baseList->Add(gcnew MyClass());
Debug::Assert(baseList[list->Count-1]->Processed); // Passes

// Upcast to interface
IList<MyClass ^>^ iList = list;
iList->Add(gcnew MyClass());
Debug::Assert(iList[iList->Count-1]->Processed); // Passes
```

Secondly, if the image processing *must* be done in the `get()` method, you can use the [decorator pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern) and create own custom collection implementing `List<MyClass ^`> that wraps an underlying `List<MyClass ^>` and does the necessary processing in its own default indexer, enumerator, `CopyTo()` and other methods that access items as required:

```
public ref class MyList : IList<MyClass ^>
{
private:
    List<MyClass ^> list;

public:
    MyList()
    {
        list = gcnew List<MyClass ^>();
    }

    virtual property MyClass^ default[int] 
    {
        MyClass^ get(int index)
        {
            MyClass^ item = list[int];
            item = ProcessItem(item); // Add your custom logic here                
            return item;                                     
        }
        void set(int index, MyClass^ value)
        {
            list[index] = value;
        }
    }

    // Implement all other methods as required.
    virtual property int Count { int get() { return list->Count; } }

    // Etc
};
```

Now the underlying list is contained within your translating list and there is no possibility the "raw" image can get accessed.

Comment: Thanks! `List<MyClass ^>::default[i]` is what I'm looking for! I have read this question while I was searching on Google. In my case, I'm pretty convinced that inheritance is a better idea than composition.

Comment: OK. This is very helpful. Thanks!